# How many number of MIPs we can generally use for Vm Creation in cloudsim or workflowsim?

Tags: virtual-machine, workflow, workflowservice, cloudsim

How many number of MIPs we can generally use for Vm Creation in cloudsim or workflowsim?

Answer (score 0):

The framework itself has no limitation on how many mips you can assign to a VM other than the one defined by its data type. In this case, as the `mips` property of the `VM` class is declared as a `double`, the maximum amount you can use is `Double.MAX_VALUE`.